# how to get difference of consecutive rows by shifting between columns

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like the one below

```
    A   B
0   a   b
1   c   d
2   e   f
3   g   h
```

How do I find the difference like below using python

```
    A   B   diff
0   a   b  Nan
1   c   d  (b-c)
2   e   f  (d-e)
3   g   h  (f-g)
```

Comment: Read the data into a Pandas data frame and use the `shift` operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,3,7], 'B':[3,1,6,4]})                 
df['diff'] = df['A'] - df['B'].shift()
```